# Comments and likes on facebook updates

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading up on the developers.facebook.com site, but they explain these things very badly. So I'm hoping some of you could explain to me how I can add a comment and like button on Facebook statuses using JavaScript and the Graph API.

What I have now is an app that displays the logged in user's home-feed (the newsfeed if you want). What I want is basic Facebook functionality, which is the ability to comment and like those statuses, images, shares etc (just like you can on Facebook), and also see others who have commented and liked those photos and statuses.

I've understood that you need to use the POST method, but I don't know I'm going to do it (there's some info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/)

So here's my code for now (I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it works. I would be glad if you could give me some constructive critics on that as well):

```
FB.api('/me/home', function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  for(var i=0, len = response.data.length; i < len; i++){ 

    var post_type = response.data[i].status_type; //Post type

    var poster_id = response.data[i].from.id; //Poster
    var poster_name = response.data[i].from.name; //Posters name
    var poster = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + poster_id + '/" >' + poster_name + '</a>'; //Link to poster
    var poster_pic  = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + poster_id + '/picture'; //Posters profile pic
    var poster_img = '<img height="50px" width="50px" src="' + poster_pic + '" />';

    var post_id = response.data[i].id; //Id of message
    var post = response.data[i].message; //Content of message
    var post_date = response.data[i].created_time; //Date created

    var object_id = response.data[i].object_id; //Pic id (if pic's an object)
    var post_img_url = response.data[i].picture; //Pic url

    if(!object_id) {
      var post_img = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + post_id + '/"> <img src="' + post_img_url + '" /> </a>'; // <a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + post_id + '/">See at Facebook</a>
    } else {
      var post_img = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + object_id + '/"> <img src="' + post_img_url + '" /> </a>';
    }

    if (!post_img_url) {
      post_img = '';
    }

    if(!post) {
      post = response.data[i].story;
    }

    if (post_type === 'wall_post') {
      if(response.data[i].to) {
        var posted_to_name = response.data[i].to.data[0].name;
        var posted_to_id = response.data[i].to.data[0].id;
        var posted_to = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + posted_to_id + '/" >' + posted_to_name + '</a>';

        document.getElementById("write").innerHTML += ('<hr> <div class="facebook_content"> <div class="facebook_left_side"> <div class="facebook_content_header"> <div class="poster_img">' + poster_img + '</div> <div class="poster">' + poster + '</div> <div class="post_type"> wrote on ' + posted_to + '\'s wall: </div> <div class="post_date">' + post_date + '</div> </div> <div class="story">' + post + '</div> </div> <div class="facebook_right_side"> <div class="img">' + post_img + '</div> </div> </div> </br>');
      } else {
        document.getElementById("write").innerHTML += ('<hr> <div class="facebook_content"> <div class="facebook_left_side"> <div class="facebook_content_header"> <div class="poster_img">' + poster_img + '</div> <div class="poster">' + poster + '</div> <div class="post_date">' + post_date + '</div> </div> <div class="story">' + post + '</div> </div> <div class="facebook_right_side"> <div class="img">' + post_img + '</div> </div> </div> </br>');
      }
    } else if (post_type === 'added_photos') {
      document.getElementById("write").innerHTML += ('<hr> <div class="facebook_content"> <div class="facebook_left_side"> <div class="facebook_content_header"> <div class="poster_img">' + poster_img + '</div> <div class="poster">' + poster + '</div> <div class="post_type"> added a photo: </div> <div class="post_date">' + post_date + '</div> </div> <div class="story">' + post + '</div> </div> <div class="facebook_right_side"> <div class="img">' + post_img + '</div> </div> </div> </br>');

} else if (post_type === 'shared_story') {
      document.getElementById("write").innerHTML += ('<hr> <div class="facebook_content"> <div class="facebook_left_side"> <div class="facebook_content_header"> <div class="poster_img">' + poster_img + '</div> <div class="poster">' + poster + '</div> <div class="post_type"> shared: </div> <div class="post_date">' + post_date + '</div> </div> <div class="story">' + post + '</div> </div> <div class="facebook_right_side"> <div class="img">' + post_img + '</div> </div> </div> </br>');

} else {
      document.getElementById("write").innerHTML += ('<hr> <div class="facebook_content"> <div class="facebook_left_side"> <div class="facebook_content_header"> <div class="poster_img">' + poster_img + '</div> <div class="poster">' + poster + '</div> <div class="post_date">' + post_date + '</div> </div> <div class="story">' + post + '</div> </div> <div class="facebook_right_side"> <div class="img">' + post_img + '</div> </div> </div> </br>');
}
  }
});
```

I obviously need to add three (or more) divs which contain the like and comment button respectably, and at least one to display the most recent comments when clicked (just as on Facebook). And I would need to add some sort of JS code which sends a request to facebook with the id of the status/image, the id of the user, what type of action is performed (like or comment) and last what the content of the comment is in that case.

The reason I'm requesting this information is that I'm working on a project, and I'm just trying out the different features of the Facebook Graph API as they could make a good addition to my project's features, and it's good to know for future references.

Hope some of you know what I can do to make it work

Sincerely,
Aleksander.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the Docs do a great job.

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/):

```
Create

You can write to the POST_ID/comments connection to post a comment to the post by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream permission and following parameters.

Parameter    Description     Type    Required
message Comment text    string   yes
```

Commenting is simple, once you have the ID of the post you want to comment on, simply run

```
 var comment = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
 var POST_ID = '1231412351234';
 FB.api('/'+POST_ID+'/comments', 'post', { message: comment }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Great! It worked!');
  }
});
```

Similarly, liking is even simplier. From the same docs:

```
You can like a Post by issuing a HTTP POST request to the POST_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. You can suppress the notification created when liking a Post by passing a notify parameter with value of false.
```

So, in Javascript:

```
 var POST_ID = '1231412351234';
 FB.api('/'+POST_ID+'/likes', 'post', function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Great! It worked!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try this as soon as I get to my computer, and will inform you if it worked or not :) 
Just one more question. How would I implement this in my already existing code? Where would I put your code and so on?

Comment: I can't help you to that detail, I'd need the entire project. Put that code where you want to like/comment.

Comment: Okay, so I've had the time to try it out now. At first it seemed to be working, but I've encountered a big problem. So, I've made an if/else check to see whether there is an object related to the post. In that case, the like function takes in the variable object_id. But if there is a standard post (without any objects) it takes the variable Post_id which is retrieved from 'response.data[i].id'. This however gives me an error message in the console (when I press the like button): "SyntaxError: At least one digit must occur after a decimal point". The id of a post looks like this: xxxxxxx_xxxxxx